# MVC 4 - Returning pdf file from action makes browser to load the action twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have an action that generates a `.pdf` document and returns it to be viewed inline on the browser.  The problem is that the browser is making a second request to the same action which is causing the app to do somethings twice each time the file gets generated.  This is what I have.

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(string id, int rp = 1, string info = "")
{        
    var doc = _service.GeneratePDF(id, rp, info);
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = $"{id}.pdf",
        Inline = true,
        Size = tickets.Length
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(doc, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(cd.FileName));
}
```

`_service.GeneratePDF` generates the PDF in memory using iTextSharp and `MemoryStream` object returning a `byte[]`

The GeneratePDF action gets called from a link in some other page:

`<a href="SomeController/GeneratePDF/1234?rp=1" target="_blank">View Document</a>`

The only thing showing on this new browser tab is the `.pdf` document.

I have tried on different browsers (Chrome, IE, FF) and the result is the same, the `.pdf` file displays properly on the browser but it requires a second call to the same action.  Any Ideas on how to prevent the browser to call the action twice?  Am I missing something on the headers?

**Edit: Browser Behavior**
[image]
First request is normal and completes with no problem.  The second one makes the action execute but the browser (or something else) cancels that request.

Comment: Showing the action isn't going to help us identify why it's getting called twice. That's like showing us a bullet and asking us to identify the shooter!

Comment: @DavidG what other info should I provide?

Comment: Action is executing twice but file is generating only once. Is that right?

Comment: Action executes twice and the file gets created twice but the browser shows only one tab with one document. See Edit: Browser Behavior.

Comment: From "[Microsoft Edge downloads PDF-files twice](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6734131/)" it sounds like this is a bug with IE Edge

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any solution ?
I have the same problem. An action generate a pdf file. This action is called twice.

I changed the *Content-Disposition* to **attachment** instead of **inline** and it's ok, the action is only called once. But of course, the file is saved and not shown in the browser.

Comment: I have done the same. Still haven't found the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem.  Bear in mind, I have NO IDEA how to actually stop this from happening, but I've come up with a work around if that helps. I looked at both requests and noticed that the referrer of the second "bogus" request is the controller action route itself (weird). However, I also noticed that the second request was disconnect from the client and a cancellation was already requested (which I'm guessing is why everything in the browser looks o.k.). I'm sure with that information, and a better understanding of MVC/routes, I could probably explain this eventually.

Anyhow, what I did was wrap my PDF generation/display code in a check for client connection. If disconnected, I return an empty view result. Like I said, total workaround, but it got me past it until someone smarter than me can explain what's happening and how to fix it.

```html
if (Response.IsClientConnected)
{
    if (pdfId == 0)
    {
        var model = _service.GetViewData(client, id);
        model.StaffName = CTCHelper.GetStaffName(model.StaffId);
        pdfId = _service.SavePDF(model, ControllerContext);
    }
    var data = _service.GetPDF(pdfId);
    var mimeType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=TESI.pdf");

    return File(data, mimeType);
}
Response.End();
return new ViewResult();
```